# Decomposition of time series: ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, time-series, statsmodels, arima

Given a trafic flow dataset from [this link](https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/agj1sjezx2wrucj5mpu2t/data.xlsx?dl=0&rlkey=i5yb5lj3ob3y7mxqc4nfsytg6), the date range is from `2021-01-01` to `2021-01-15`, for each day hour range is `10:00:02` to `12:00:00` with frequency of `2minutes`.

```
df.head()
Out[145]: 
   trafic flow count                date
0               30.0 2021-01-01 10:02:00
1               38.0 2021-01-01 10:04:00
2               27.0 2021-01-01 10:06:00
3               31.0 2021-01-01 10:08:00
4               29.0 2021-01-01 10:10:00

df.tail()
Out[146]: 
     trafic flow count                date
895               28.0 2021-01-15 11:52:00
896               41.0 2021-01-15 11:54:00
897               19.0 2021-01-15 11:56:00
898               15.0 2021-01-15 11:58:00
899               18.0 2021-01-15 12:00:00
```

Next step I need to using `ARIMA` model to forecast `2021-01-16`'s trafic flow, but I get an error during decomposition:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from statsmodels.tsa.stattools import adfuller
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose

df = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
df = df.set_index('date')
def adf_test(timeseries):
    # perform Dickey-Fuller test:
    print ('Results of Dickey-Fuller Test:')
    dftest = adfuller(timeseries, autolag='AIC')
    dfoutput = pd.Series(dftest[0:4], index=['Test Statistic','p-value','#Lags Used','Number of Observations Used'])
    for key,value in dftest[4].items():
       dfoutput['Critical Value (%s)'%key] = value
    print (dfoutput)

# apply adf test on the series
adf_test(df['trafic flow count'])

df_log = np.log(df)
plt.plot(df_log)

decomposition = seasonal_decompose(df_log)
trend = decomposition.trend
seasonal = decomposition.seasonal
residual = decomposition.resid

plt.figure(figsize=(20, 7))
plt.subplot(411)
plt.plot(df_log, label="Original")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.subplot(412)
plt.plot(trend, label="Trend")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.subplot(413)
plt.plot(seasonal, label="Seasonability")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.subplot(414)
plt.plot(residual, label="Residuals")
plt.legend(loc="best")
plt.tight_layout()
```

Out:

```
ValueError: You must specify a period or x must be a pandas object with a DatetimeIndex with a freq not set to None
```

Why did I get this error and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Any time series object must contain a time period. In your case there is no time. Anywhere where is your dataset? Can you just show the head of the dataset that you are using here

Comment: Sure, but I think you may click `this link` in the question and download it from dropbox.

Comment: No need to download I just want to view it. Clicked on the link and it wanted me to sign up for dropbox

Comment: Ok, sorry about that, I updated the head and tail of data.

Comment: I see your data is not a time series object and therefore cannot be decomposed. Ensure your data is a time series object. ie only ONE COLUMN. the date column should be the indiex column

Comment: I've used `df = df.set_index('date')` converting `date` column as index.

Comment: Yes. and ensure the index is of dtype date and not object. Then you can now do the decomposition

Comment: It seems I add to add more parameters using: `seasonal_decompose(df, model='additive', extrapolate_trend='freq', period=1)`

Comment: yes, that is correct. Hope there are no errors anymore. Note that you can set the index when reading the ata directly ie `pd.read_excel(...,, index_col = 'date', parse_dates = True)`